# Google glass sdk for Epson moverio

Tags: epson

What I understand from technical specs of Google glass is that it displays a 2D plane on one of the eye's projector. Android sdk in addition with GDK provides tools for writing apps for the device with features that can sense eye and voice actions. But, it **does not provide 3D stereoscopic vision** as this would require projector on both eyes.

On the other hand Epson Moverio promises true 3D augmented reality experience Having used Moverio, I can see two projector for both eyes that is able to project steroscopic images.

Perhaps I should have done a more extensive research regarding the spectrum of products/toolkit available, still I have some Questions/Doubts of which until now I could not find any information.

Q1. Does google provide any 2-eye-projector kind of glasses product?
**ANS: No**

Q2. Does google glasses development kit (the api) provides features for generating left & right views for a 3D object for EPSON Moverio? I have seen that Wikitude and Metaio comes with these kind of features. Did google provide any support in gdk?
**ANS: NO. Not from google.**

Q3. Does Epson plan to roll out any developer's tool for easily create 3D markers and plot them in the projected space?
**ANS: Not announced yet from EPSON.**

Comment: 1) What does google tell you? 2) What does the [GDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/) tell you? 3) What does EPSON tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current support in Google Glass for stereoscopic views.